# C# override base form text - InitializeComponent

Tags: c#

Problem: When I execute my code it pulls up the code correctly from the inherited base class and changes the text of the base form correctly.  But as soon as I, in debugger mode in VS2013, come back into the derived class and step over the InitizlieComponent(); call everything is reverted back. When I say 'reverted back' I mean that thing go back to the way that they were in the designer for the derived form.

All help would be appreciated!

Derived Class

```
public partial class appSuiteMenu : App.baseForm
{
    public appSuiteMenu()
        : base("App Suite")
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Base Class

```
public partial class baseForm : Form
{
   public baseForm() { InitializeComponent(); }  //Required or designer breaks
   public baseForm(string formTitle=null)
   {
      this.initialize(formTitle);   
   }

   private void initialize(string formTitle)
   {
      base.text = formTitle + " - " + //Other objects are called from the class
   }

   public override string Text
   {
      get 
      { 
         return base.Text;          
       }
       set 
       { 
          base.Text = value;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be the second call to the "InitializeComponent()" inside the derived class.

What is does, is exactly what you said. It overrwrites everything from the base initialization.

I believe you can remove it and it'll be fine:

```
public appSuiteMenu()
            : base("App Suite")
        {

        }
```

Read more about it in here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/initializecomponent

**Edit:**

Here is some tests I did with two forms. One is derived from the other. The base form hase a label. The second from adds another label. When creating a form of the derived type, tou get a form with two labels. What I did was use InitializeComponent(); in both base and derived forms.

The code:

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form
    {
        public BaseForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = "asdf";
        }
    }
...
public partial class DerivedForm : BaseForm
    {
        public DerivedForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label2.Text = "asdfasfd";
        }
    }
```

What happens in execution of the code is that the base initialization happens. Then the derived initialization adds only the add functionality.
It seems pretty straightforward, but Iv'e noticed you had only one InitializeComponent(); in the code above that will actually happen.

Comment: Dave, Thanks for the reply.  If I remove the InitializeComponent() inside the derived class and execute my code then the base form is what displays.  It does display the correct text as I wanted my code to do.  However, ALL the controls and code that I wrote on the form (appSuiteMenu()) does not show.  My assumption is that VS builds, binds and displays all of these controls on the form when in call InitializeComponent() from the derived class.  So, obviously I'm don't understand something.  What could it be?

Comment: Hey, That makes some sense. Read the documentaion I add, and try and look inside the autogenerated code in the designer. Then you'll realize exactly what each InitializeComponent() is putting inside your form.
In addition you can debug this code segment and find out when all of your desired controls are added/deleted.

Hope you find your answer

Comment: Your link to DotNetPerls helped confirm my suspicion.  Since I used the designer to place controls on the derived form it will be overwritten once the InitializeComponenet() method is called.  

How is form inheritance suppose to work if I'm passing parameters to the base form constructor?

Comment: That's great! If you found me helpful I would appreciate an upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Dave,
Your edited posted is nearly what I ended up doing to correct my problem.  Since I was overriding the .Text() property of the base form, I found that I didn't even have to pass anything in the constructor.  Simply setting the form text in the code, or designer, changed everything for me.